# How can i keep shape of div constructed by max-width, max-height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need div to keep required shape (width/height proportion), for instance square and at the same time div should occupy as much as possible of the parent container within set limits, for instance up to 90% of the height and up to 60% of the width. I can achieve it with the help of the javascript but i would like to see css solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = Math.min($('div').width(),$('div').height());
  $('div').width(a).height(a);
});
```

```css
html,body {
  height:100%;
}

div {
  max-width:60%;
  max-height:90%;
  height:100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: You can use `display: flex;` or `display: grid`

Comment: I don't think you can compare height with width, with just CSS, but what's the problem with using JS for this ?

Comment: I was trying to solve it with display: flex; etc. but despite spending few hours somehow i couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I entirely understand the question, but there is a css only way to maintain aspect ratio while setting a fluid width.

You can set a width in percentage, and use padding-bottom set to a percent to add the height.

This will keep the aspect ratio the same as the width changes on resize.

```
div {
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
}
```

[Example Codepen](https://codepen.io/danbernardi/pen/aKYveE).

You may need to mess with the padding-bottom percent until it matches your desired aspect ratio.

Comment: Yes but padding-bottom doesn't seem to work with max-height. I wish that box won't exceed maximum percentage of the outer element.